# Designing Character Other Than Temperature for Simulated Annealing on Combinatorial Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, simulation

Many research on designing temperature for simulated annealing is carried out. We wonder if there is any research on designing general feature of the Hamiltonian used in Simulated Annealing.

For example, consider the Ising optimization problem on a very large graph: at each time, a random vertex $v$ is choosen; one updates the state of that vertex according to a certain distribution on $\{-1,1\}$. The distribution must be decided using the subgraph consisting vertexes within certain distance to $v$. The way to decide on a distribution is called *updating strategy*. The goal is to maximize the Ising Hamiltonian in fixed amount of steps via an updating strategy. Simulated Annealing updates each vertex according to the conditional distribution (with respect to the Ising Hamiltonian), i.e., optimizing Ising Hamiltonian via Ising Hamiltonian. But to optimize Ising Hamiltonian, Ising Hamiltonian is unlikely to be the best.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. In quite general terms, we seek a state $s_0$ that minimizes $E[s]$, through a sequence of transitions from states $s$ to $s'$ with "temperature" $T$-dependent probability $P(E[s],E[s'],T)$. For high $T$ the probability allows for transitions with $E[s']>E[s]$, as $T$ is lowered these become less and less probable. There exist many strategies on how to choose the temperature, and how to lower it as the simulation proceeds, but although the title of the question says "designing better temperature", that is not what you are asking, is it?

Comment: You are right. I'm asking whether there are research focus on designing characters of the Hamiltonian other than temperature.